# Elaboration on XSL code

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to group(merge) children of same nodes in my XML document. 
I have found a similar topic where I got some **sample code**, but my XML is more complicated and twisted and I would need to truly understand the logic of the syntax of the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="concat(@ID, '___', @Key)" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Groups>
      <!--
      Iterate over a node set containing just one GroupData element for
      each combination of ID and Key
      -->
      <xsl:for-each select="/Groups/GroupData[count( . | key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))[1]) = 1]">
        <GroupData>
          <!-- Copy attributes from the "prototype" GroupData -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <!--
          Copy ItemData children from *all* GroupData elements with matching
          ID/Key
          -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))/ItemData" />
        </GroupData>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Groups>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **sample** XML code of that XSL is:

```
<GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="zzz" Value="3"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="yyy" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="abc" Value="3"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="zzz" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="pqr" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="zzz" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="tuv" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
```

So I would like to understand the XSL code so I can apply it for my case.

Can someone elaborate it for me? And more precisely these parts:

```
<xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="concat(@ID, '___', @Key)" />
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Groups/GroupData[count( . | key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))[1]) = 1]">
        <GroupData>
          <!-- Copy attributes from the "prototype" GroupData -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <!--
          Copy ItemData children from *all* GroupData elements with matching
          ID/Key
          -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))/ItemData" />
        </GroupData>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:key name=""/>` creates an index of XML-nodes in the document, using the specified expression as look-up-key. This is to make it easier to find similar nodes. In XSL 1.x, this is the main means of grouping nodes. `key(name, key)` is used to query this index.

In your case

```
/Groups/GroupData[count( . | key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))[1]) = 1]
```

basicly means: Find all `GroupData` nodes that come first in the index for the specified key. This could also be written as:

```
/Groups/GroupData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-data', concat(@ID, '___', @Key))[1])]
```

The `generate-id()` method creates a unique id for any node in the document. It makes it possible to compare nodes for equality. If no argument is provided, it uses the active node (`.`)